# Command already defined

Tags: exam, knitr

I came across an odd problem compiling LaTeX [`exam.cls`](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam/exam.cls) document producing with [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/). Pasted below is minimal reproducible code.

`knitr` compiles fine, but `pdflatex` terminated with:

- Command `\framed` already defined.
- Command `\shaded` already defined.
- Command `\leftbox` already defined.

It seems the author of `exam.cls` pasted most of the framed.sty into the class file, which is generating conflicts with anyone who actually wants to load the original `framed.sty` package, including `knitr`.

My ugly solution to an ugly problem was to modify `exam.cls` file:

```
% Original
\newenvironment{framed}% using default \FrameCommand
  {\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
  {\endMakeFramed}

% Modified
\newenvironment{exam-framed}% using default \FrameCommand
  {\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
  {\endMakeFramed}

% Same for "\newenvironment{shaded}" and "\newenvironment{leftbar}"
```

I would like to find more elegant solution, not rewriting original `exam.cls` file.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You could add a `\let\<name>\relax` for each previously defined `<name>`.  This should eliminate the need to change the `.cls` file.

Comment: @Andrej: Note that for environments you have two macros defined - a start and an end. See Heiko's answer for some reference to that. So, for `\framed`, there's also `\endframed`; `\shaded` and `\endshaded`; `\leftbox` and `\endleftbox`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Renaming using `\let`

Name clashes can be resolved by renaming. In this case these are simple environments. An environment `name` defines two macros `\name` and `\endname` (the latter can also left undefined, because it is called via `\csname`).

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcommand*{\renameenviron}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname exam-#1\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname endexam-#1\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname end#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
}
\renameenviron{framed}
\renameenviron{shaded}
\renameenviron{leftbar}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

However this method overwrites the internal stuff of `framed` in `exam` by the original code of package `framed`, see below for further discussion.

### Simulate package loading

The class `exam` says:

> ```
> % Donald Arseneau <...>, who created the excellent
> % ``framed.sty'' and generously allowed me to include basically the
> % whole thing in exam.cls, making the few changes needed for it to
> % work well with question environments:
> % framed.sty   v 0.8a   21-Jul-2003
> % Copyright (C) 1992-2003 by Donald Arseneau
> % These macros may be freely transmitted, reproduced, or modified
> % provided that this notice is left intact.
> ```

That could mean, `framed` is already loaded. It might not make sense to load it twice.
Then LaTeX can be tricked to think that the package is already loaded:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\providecommand\expandafter*\csname ver@framed.sty\endcsname
{2003/07/21 v0.8a Simulated by exam}
\makeatother
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

### The long story

Both methods above do not address the question, what has changed in the implementation of `framed` in class `exam` to the original `framed`. The environments are one side, the internal stuff the other side. For example, internal macros are defined using `\def` that does not generate an error, if the macro is already defined. In the first method, the later loaded package `framed` overwrites the internal stuff of class `exam`. In the second method the version of `framed` in class `exam` is used.

Advantage of the first method: The latest `framed` is used including bug fixes and new features (if there are any). On the downside, the changes of `exam` are lost
(A quick look reveals some margin and positioning stuff). Therefore the second method might be better here.

If you are lucky, the second method already works for your document.

Otherwise it can be that this `knitr` requires a later version of `framed` or expects an unmodified `framed`. These cases cause lots of work, because the different macro versions need to be analyzed for differences and merging or providing different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem too 3 minutes ago!  Googling for an answer landed me immediately on this page - thank you all for taking the time - very helpful, much appreciated!

My LaTeX code using the `exam` class was compiling perfectly fine using MiKTeX/texstudio, but as indicated in the question, copying this code into an `.Rnw` document and knitting it, i.e. compiling PDF caused the exact same problem detailed in the question - same 3 errors.

I looked at the answers provided here, but seems like I would need to edit `exam.cls`, if my understanding is accurate - not sure I want to do that - what if this gets updated? Then every time, I need to edit it again?

Instead, I used a solution suggested by YiHui Xie, the author of the `knitr` package and it works beautifully:

Copied from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/sNZyM4Y3ETk

"...
The other solution is to use the listings package by putting a chunk
like this in your document:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@
```

In most cases the `listings` package is more robust. The `framed` package
is quite fragile. 
..."

I did precisely that:

```
\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@
```

And the rest of my document as before.  Compiles WITHOUT any errors!

if I comment this chunk out, I get the exact same error as @Andrej

```
Command \framed already defined.
Command \shaded already defined.
Command \leftbox already defined.
```